How to Center a Full-Width Dropdown Menu in React TypeScript Using TailwindCSS
I'm having trouble styling a dropdown menu for my portfolio site using React TypeScript and TailwindCSS. I'm currently using a hover method to trigger the dropdown, and it remains open when you hover over the dropdown menu itself, which is expected behavior.
However, I'm facing an issue when I add more links to the dropdown menu. The menu is currently centered based on the text above it, and I've set the width to be full-screen (w-screen). This causes the dropdown menu to overflow the screen width, which is not the desired outcome. I want the dropdown menu to be both centered and take up the full width of the screen without causing overflow.
Here’s the code snippet for my current setup:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";
import { DownOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import profilePicture from "../../assets/Profile-picture-without-me.jpg";
import MenuIcon from "./MenuIcon.tsx";
import Menu from "./Menu.tsx";

interface NavbarProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    FlyoutContent?: React.FC;
};

const Example = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const toggleMenu = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    };

    return (
        <div className="navigation-container">
            <nav className="navigation-inner-container">
                <div className="flex justify-between items-center p-3 mx-auto w-[90%] max-w-[1340px] lg:w-[95%]">

                    {/* Logo Section */}
                    <div className="navigation-logo flex justify-start items-center h-10 w-10">
                        <img className="rounded-sm" src={profilePicture} alt="Profile picture"></img>
                    </div>

                    <div className="navbar-links-container hidden lg:block">
                        <div className="navigation-links-wrapper flex gap-x-8 w-auto h-auto">

                            {/* Projects 1 */}
                            <FlyoutLink FlyoutContent={ProjectTypes}>
                                <Link to="/projects" className="font-semibold text-xl">Projects</Link>
                                <DownOutlined className="py-auto" />
                            </FlyoutLink>

                            {/* Projects 2 */}
                            <FlyoutLink FlyoutContent={ProjectTypes}>
                                <Link to="/projects" className="font-semibold text-xl">Projects</Link>
                                <DownOutlined className="py-auto" />
                            </FlyoutLink>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {/* Menu Button for Mobile */}
                    <div className="menu-button lg:hidden flex justify-end items-center">
                        <button onClick={toggleMenu}>
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            {/* Mobile Menu Display */}
            {
                isOpen && (
                    <div className="mobile-menu flex flex-col items-start bg-white shadow-md p-4 absolute top-16 left-0 w-full z-50 lg:hidden">
                        <Menu />
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </div >
    );
};

const FlyoutLink: React.FC<NavbarProps> = ({ children, FlyoutContent }) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const showFlyout = FlyoutContent && open;

    return (
        <div
            onMouseEnter={() => setOpen(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setOpen(false)}
            className="relative w-fit h-fit"
        >
            <div className="relative">
                {children}
                <span
                    style={{
                        transform: showFlyout ? "scaleX(1)" : "scaleX(0)",
                    }}
                    className="absolute -bottom-2 -left-2 -right-2 h-1 origin-left scale-x-0 rounded-full bg-indigo-300 transition-transform duration-300 ease-out"
                />
            </div>
            <AnimatePresence>
                {showFlyout && (
                    <motion.div
                        initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 15 }}
                        animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
                        exit={{ opacity: 0, y: 15 }}
                        transition={{ duration: 0.3, ease: "easeOut" }}
                        className="absolute left-1/2 top-12 w-[calc(100vw-17px)] !-translate-x-1/2 bg-white z-10"
                    >
                        <div className="absolute -top-6 left-0 right-0 h-6 bg-transparent" />
                        <div className="absolute left-1/2 top-0 h-4 w-4 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 rotate-45" />
                        <FlyoutContent />
                    </motion.div>
                )}
            </AnimatePresence>
        </div>
    );
};

const ProjectTypes = () => {
    return (
        <div className="menu-projects-container">
            <div className="menu-projects-wrapper flex justify-evenly shadow-2xl pb-8">
                <div className="subproject-container flex gap-x-2 border-b-2 border-b-black py-4">
                    <h3 className="text-black/50">/01</h3>
                    <h1 className="text-2xl font-medium">GitHub Projects</h1>
                    <div className="arrow-container flex justify-center items-center w-8 h-8">
                        <img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/66bf407255e2bbac50fde356/66bf9e7b27401f68266d92b9_Arrow%20-%20Right.svg" alt="Arrow"></img>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="subproject-container flex gap-x-2 border-b-2 border-b-black py-4">
                    <h3 className="text-black/50">/02</h3>
                    <h1 className="text-2xl font-medium">School Projects</h1>
                    <div className="arrow-container flex justify-center items-center w-8 h-8">
                        <img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/66bf407255e2bbac50fde356/66bf9e7b27401f68266d92b9_Arrow%20-%20Right.svg" alt="Arrow"></img>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Example;

The only time the dropdown menu centers correctly is when there is only one navbar element. In this case, the dropdown is centered exactly in the middle of the screen. However, when there are multiple navbar elements, the dropdown aligns based on the text above it, causing it to overflow the screen's width.
Here is a live version of the code.
Any guidance on how to properly center the dropdown menu and make it take the full width of the screen without overflowing would be greatly appreciated!

If you provide reproduceable code or example that would be more useful. You can use jsfiddle or codesandbox for that.

I ran the source you provided in react and it looks like the attached image. Can you explain it in more detail in this image? https://postimg.cc/dD2MGK30 I will delete the comments once the request is confirmed.

I provided live version of my code. Fsr, in your code, I see them rendered vertically. I want them to be horizontally. Check out the live version and be sure to set bigger width of your screen. Just then, it will render full content.
